# Turn off Limited Hero mode Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

I just started playing Dota 2, and I want to know why I can't turn off limited hero mode.  Unchecking the Limited Heroes checkbox disables the Save Settings button so apparently I'm not allowed.

I am playing Normal matches, not Ranked matches, because my profile is not yet level 13.  Can you not play with all heroes in Normal matches?

Comment: Isn't it part of the tutorial you have to complete? What level are you?

Comment: I'm level 5, and I haven't completed the tutorial.  I'll try that.

Comment: Wow, there is a lot of training.

Comment: No training required. I had unchecked Limited Hero mode, but never checked another checkbox. They should be radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: @jcarpenter radiobuttons imply that only 1 can be selected at any given time. They should make a popup instead like "at least 1 mode must be selected"

Comment: My understanding is that you need to have at least one game mode selected - is this definitely the case? i.e. do you have All Pick selected while you are trying to unselect Limited Heroes?

Comment: Cool I understand, I didn't realize I had to select All Pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I never selected All Pick.

I didn't realize you had to select All Pick; I thought All Pick was just the default, and Limited Heroes etc. were all modifiers you could apply.

Valve should change some of the checkboxes to radio buttons, or add a validation message or something.

Comment: If you'd like to suggest that, register at "dev.dota2.com". that is the official valve development forum where user feedback will be read and considered.

Comment: this answer could use some work. You should state where you can select all pick from. Otherwise people will look in options not under the green find match button where it is actually located (in game modes).